# ESP8266 sometimes stuck on AT+CIPSEND with "busy s..."

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, softwareserial

I'm using an ESP8266-01S Wi-Fi module on an Arduino UNO.

When I use `AT+CIPSEND=4` and then type `test` it successfully sends that message to my laptop. However, sometimes the module returns a `busy s...` after typing the message... Then the module board is "frozen" for a couple of seconds to a full minute before accepting other commands.

What's a way to make sure the message gets send without getting that `busy s...` response. Or how do I catch it and reset the board or something like that?